# Angular2: Styling the 'loading..' element

Tags: angular

I'm trying to style the root component, specifically the 'loading..' content that's shown while an app bootstraps. I know that I can load a stylesheet in `index.html` and access classes that I've added within the `<my-app>` selector. However I assume this can be done with styles that are assigned in the `@Component` decorator on root app class.

I've created a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8bpwuBwa03eN98MOpPwA?p=preview). The question is, how can I get the `loading...` message to be styled (for instance, change the text color to red) using component-based styles?

Thanks.

Comment: What you want is not possible. Because once the root component gets initialized, the `loading...` message will be replaced by the component's html. Your only option is to have the stylesheet on index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<div .primary>
```

To

```
<div class="primary">
```

Then in your style.css add the following:

```
.primary {
   color: red;
}
```

This will change the "loading..." text to red every time it is shown.
I think this is the best way to make this happen rather than using styles or styleUrls inside a component that will only pertain to the component that it is called.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

updated your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jwYtzkv8dgDrwVU6tPY3?p=preview), not sure what do you mean by  component-based styles?

```
   .primary{
      font-size: 20px;
      color: red;
    }

    <div class="primary" >loading...</div>
```